# Can`t add stored procedure in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2012, stored-procedures

I'm trying to add a stored procedure in the Server Explorer in Visual Studio 2012. Connection works fine. So far as I know there should be the option to add a new stored procedure, but it is missing. Am I missing something or is there a workaround in SQL Management Studio?

Thx for any hint and help in advance!

[image]

UPDATE:

I updated to VS 2013 and there it was finally shown

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using the `Server Explorer` window, you should be using the `SQL Server Object Explorer` window.

Comment: Thx for the hint! But I didn't find it in VS 2012. I updated to VS 2013 and there I was finally able to find the beloved SQL Server Object Explorer as shown in the update above.

Comment: Wild guess: you didn't have SQL Server Data Tools installed for Visual Studio 2012.